# I can not display my input in two blocks of two aside

Tags: html, css

I have four inputs and i want them to be displayed like this:

```
Input1    Input3
Input2    Input4
```

instead they get displayed like this:

```
Input1
Input2
Input3
Input4
```

I have tried to surround them with divs and made the inner one `display: block` an the outher one `display: inline`. It does not work.

```css
.inputDiv {
  display: block;
}

.rowDiv {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form id="task1">
    <div id="row1" class="rowDiv">
      <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
        <input id="i1">
      </div>
      <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
        <input id="i2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="rowDiv">
      <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
        <input id="i3">
      </div>
      <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
        <input id="i4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to display it so that it looks the right way and explain how it can be done in a good programming style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `rowDiv`  to `inline-block`. This way you have the whole container as `inline` but the contents as `block`:

```
.rowDiv {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

As you can understand from `w3schools`:

> `inline-block` displays an element as an inline-level block container

```css
.inputDiv{
  display: block;
}
.rowDiv{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <head>
 <h1>
  header
 </h1>
</head>
<form id="task1">
 <div id="row1" class="rowDiv">
  <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
    <input id="i1">
  </div>
  <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
    <input id="i2">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="row2" class="rowDiv">
  <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
    <input id="i3">
  </div>
  <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
    <input id="i4">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the difference of inline and inline-block. I will use this.

Comment: So happy that it was helpful. It was my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

You might need to treat the two divs as column inside a row.

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

.col50 {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id="task1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col50">
      <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
        <input id="i1">
      </div>
      <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
        <input id="i2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col50">
      <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
        <input id="i3">
      </div>
      <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
        <input id="i4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS Like

```
.rowDiv{
    display: inline-block;
  }
.inputDiv{
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/cmydhgkb/4/

Comment: Thank you, i will use inline-block now.

Answer (score 1):

U need to keep `display: -webkit-box` or `display: inline-block` for rowDiv and it will work fine. Below u can check in code snippet.

```css
.inputDiv{
        display: block;
      }
.rowDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <h1>
  header
 </h1>
</head>
<form id="task1">
 <div id="row1" class="rowDiv">
  <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
    <input id="i1">
  </div>
  <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
    <input id="i2">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="row2" class="rowDiv">
  <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
    <input id="i3">
  </div>
  <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
    <input id="i4">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not ordered as they want

Answer (score 1):

So no more complex! Just need to change to `display:flex;` in your **`<form>` Element** like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/limitbrk/h8Ldprfs/)

```css
#task1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <head>
    <h1>
      header
    </h1>
  </head>
  <form id="task1" class="flex  in-non-flex  work-like-row">
    <div class="non-flex  in-flex  work-like-col">
      <div class="non-flex  in-non-flex  work-like-row">
        <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
        <input id="i1">
      </div>
      <div class="non-flex  in-non-flex  work-like-row">
        <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
        <input id="i2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="non-flex  in-flex  work-like-col">
      <div class="non-flex  in-non-flex  work-like-row">
        <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
        <input id="i3">
      </div>
      <div class="non-flex  in-non-flex  work-like-row">
        <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
        <input id="i4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this code..

**css**

```
.rowDiv {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.inputDiv {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.inputDiv {
  display: block;
   width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.rowDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <h1>
  header
 </h1>
</head>
<form id="task1">
 <div id="row1" class="rowDiv">
  <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
    <input id="i1">
  </div>
  <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
    <input id="i2">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="row2" class="rowDiv">
  <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
    <input id="i3">
  </div>
  <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
    <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
    <input id="i4">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not ordered as they want

Answer (score 1):

```css
.inputDiv {
  display: block;
}

.rowDiv {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form id="task1">
    <div id="row1" class="rowDiv">
      <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
        <input id="i1">
      </div>
      <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
        <input id="i2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="rowDiv">
      <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
        <input id="i3">
      </div>
      <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
        <input id="i4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </for
```

Comment: Thank you, for this solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display:flex to your form element.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.inputDiv {
  display: block;
}

.rowDiv {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form id="task1" class="d-flex">
    <div id="row1" class="rowDiv">
      <div id="i1div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i1">i1</lable>
        <input id="i1">
      </div>
      <div id="i2div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i2">i2</lable>
        <input id="i2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2" class="rowDiv">
      <div id="i3div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i3">i3</lable>
        <input id="i3">
      </div>
      <div id="i4div" class="inputDiv">
        <lable for="i4">i4</lable>
        <input id="i4">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property to position your elements, and keep a small & clean html code.

Here's [a cool cheatsheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) that I use daily :)

```css
section{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  justify-content: center;
}

input{
  width: 45%;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input1" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="input2" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="input3" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="input4" />
</section>
```

Comment: Not ordered as they want

Comment: Oops, yeah sorry :/